# SimpleXML Java - Read value in the root element

Tags: android, simple-framework

I am using SimpleXML for Java to parse a XML response to java class mapping. However, I am not able to get this particular piece working with my android device.

My XML fragment looks like this,

```
            <t:EmailAddresses>
              <t:Entry Key="EmailAddress1">sip:xxx@abs.com</t:Entry>
              <t:Entry Key="EmailAddress2">smtp:xxx@abs.com</t:Entry>
              <t:Entry Key="EmailAddress3">SMTP:xxx@abs.com</t:Entry>
            </t:EmailAddresses>
```

and my Class definition for EmailAddresses looks like this,

```
    @Root
    public class EmailAddresses 
    {
       @ElementList
       private List<Entry> Entry;

       public List<Entry> getEntry() { return Entry; }
       public void setEntry(List<Entry> entry) { Entry = entry; }
    }
```

And my Entry class looks like this,

```
    @Element
    public class Entry 
    {
        @Attribute
        private String Key;

        public String getKey() { return Key; }
        public void setKey(String key) { Key = key; }
    }
```

when I parse run the parser, I only get the Keys and that also, I get "Multiple Root Elements" error when trying to parse all 3 into a List of Entry class.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?? Thanks !!

Note: The XML Namespace "t" is defined properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some things you should change:

**Class `EmailAddresses`**

```
@Root(name = "EmailAddresses") /* 1 */
@Namespace(prefix = "t", reference = "INSERT YOUR REFERENCE HERE!") /* 2 */
public class EmailAddresses
{
    @ElementList(inline = true) /* 3 */
    private List<Entry> Entry;

    // ...
}
```

**Explanation:**

- **`/* 1 */`**: Set the name of the element (case sensitive); simple does this per default, but so you can ensure it's really correct.
- **`/* 2 */`**: Set the namespace and it's reference; required for the `t` in your XML.
- **`/* 3 */`**: Inline the list; the `<t:EmailAddresses>` element is constructed out of the `@Root()` element, all entries follow as
  inline-elements. Otherwise the list will create another element as child,
  wrapping it's entries.

**Class `Entry`**

```
@Root(name = "Entry") /* 1 */
@Namespace(prefix = "t", reference = "INSERT YOUR REFERENCE HERE!") /* 2 */
public class Entry
{
    @Text
    private String text; /* 3 */
    @Attribute
    private String Key;

    // ...
}
```

**Explanation:**

- **`/* 1 */`**: Don't use `@Element` here, use `@Root()`.
- **`/* 2 */`**: As #2 above.
- **`/* 3 */`**: Your `Entry`-tags in the XML contain text (= value of the element, like the *"sip:..."*), those require a mapping too. If the text is optional, you can use `@Text(required = false)` to indicate that.

***TIP:** Create an instance of your list, fill it with entries and serialize it, e.g. into a file. So you can see if the mapping is matching your expectations, and where you have to do some corrections.*

Comment: I am going to try this out @ollo .. I ll get back to you . Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use attributes to extract the data?  Here's a snippet from an RSS feed reader app that parses XML similarly:

```
if (localName.equals("channel"))
{
    /** Get attribute value */
    String attr = attributes.getValue("category");
    itemList.setTitle(attr);
}
```

Comment: How would this fit into my XML fragment? Well.. is the above code with SimpleXML ??